# Whitespace on the right side of webpage

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a strange whitespace on the webpage I'm helping design for my friend and I don't know how to get rid of it. The website isn't even done so hopefully this doesn't count as advertising: http://mow4me.com/

Can someone tell me why this is happening because I've been looking at the elements with Chrome's dev tools and nothing seems to be sticking out...

EDIT: the website looks proper in IE...

Comment: I do not see any whitespace in chrome  (MAC)

Comment: I see 'white-space', but only because the page-contents are centred, I think. What browser and which platform?

Comment: I'm using chrome 19 dev I believe and it also shows in mobile safari and firefox

edit: i took off the text-align: center at the top but it still has that problem

Comment: The page looks the same for me in IE, FF and Chrome. Where exactly on the page is the "strange whitespace" occuring?

Comment: I just checked in chrome/ie on windows 7 and can see the gap , which can be attributed to margin: 32px;
padding: 24px;

Comment: Cant see what your talking about (Win 7 Chrome 20), maybe post a screen shot.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/89veq screenshot

@Satya what element are you talking about?

Comment: @Satya, weird: Chrome 18's not picking up any `margin` or `padding` on `.chartstep` for me, just `position` and dimensions (720x0).

Comment: `<div class="paragraph">` really? Can't you use a `p`? And <div class="nav"> without a single link? Why not a nav, ul, 5 li and an a per item? No label next to each checkbox? Associated with for/id mechanism to their respective checkbox, they would allow to click on the large label and not force into aiming for the small form element. That's a feature known from some people, even complete noobs at least for checkbox and radio.

Comment: @Felipe this is a mockup, sorry if you thought I actually finished the site when clearly I didn't.

I'll take your advice on the <p> thing though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .chart-step is inheriting its width of 100% from its parent (#chart-wrapper).

This 720px width, combined with your left position of 400px is your issue.

just define its width:

```
.chart-step { width:192px}
```

Comment: this works thanks! I have to wait for 4 minutes to accept it though